# Google Compute Engine - Low on Resource Utilisation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine

I use a VM Instance provided by Google Compute Engine.

```
Machine Type: n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory).
```

When I check for the CPU Utilisation, it never uses more than 12%. I use my VM for running Jupyter Notebook. I have tried loading dataframes which costed 7.5 GiB (And it takes a long time to process the data for simple operations). But still the utilisation is same

How can I utilise the CPU power ~ 100%?

Or Does my program use only 1 out of the 8 CPU (1/8)*100 =12.5%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [stress](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) command to impose a configurable amount of CPU, memory, I/O, and disk stress on the system.

Example to stress 4 cores for 90 seconds:

`stress --cpu 4 --timeout 90`

In the meantime go to your [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) on your browser to check your CPU usage on your VM or open new SSH connection to your VM and run [TOP](https://www.tecmint.com/12-top-command-examples-in-linux/) command to see your CPU status.

After running those mentioned commands, if your CPU can reach over 99%, your instance is working fine and you have to check your application resources to know why it is restricted and cannot use CPU more than 12%.